No module named '_ctypes' despite trying various methods
I am using venv within wsl in vscode for windows machine. Despite installing requirements.txt everytime I run python -m main.py I get this error :
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'.

When I run which python it points to the directory within the venv. I have also tried running sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
I get this response:
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.4.2-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded

I'm not sure how to resolve this now.

I have tried this in Windows and WSL, in both case in the normal environment and a venv. In all cases it succeeded. Is there something in your requirements.txt file that is affecting things? I am also unsure what connection libffi-dev has to this problem.

ctypes comes with a Python installation. You have an installation issue.

I have tried reinstalling python but it doesn't resolve the issue as well

Start with something simple. Can you runPython interactively from the command line and import ctypes successfully? There’s really not enough information for us to help you
